# Request execution goes too long time

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm looking for some suggestion or optimization.
Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MilestonesAndFlags(
    id SERIAL,
    site_id BIGINT,
    milestone BIGINT,
    value BIGINT,
    TIMESTAMP BIGINT,
    timestamp_confirmation BIGINT,
    COMMENT TEXT,
    INDEX(site_id),
    INDEX(milestone),
    INDEX(milestone,site_id)
);
```

In this table I store different milestones with timestamp (to be able to make historical view of any changes) per different sites. Table has about million rows at that time.

The problem occures when I try to get latest actual milestone value per sites using queries like

```
SELECT site_id,
       value
FROM SitesMilestonesAndFlags
WHERE id IN
        (SELECT max(id)
         FROM SitesMilestonesAndFlags
         WHERE milestone=1
         GROUP BY milestone,
                  site_id);
```

This request execution time is higher 5 minutes on my PC..
`EXPLAIN` seems to be OK:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table              | type | possible_keys         | key         | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | MilestonesAndFlags | ALL  | NULL                  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 1111320| Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | MilestonesAndFlags | ref  | milestone,milestone_2 | milestone_2 | 9       | const |  180660| Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Any suggestion about more correct query or table structure?
MySQL >= 5.5

Comment: Create a primary index on `id` column as well. Also, this appears to be postgresql instead of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot and propose that you use a `temporary aliased table` instead of the where statement that is a `dependent subquery`. Not sure if mysql optimized or runs the subquery for every row of the main/outer query.

It would be very interesting if you ran the queries on large data sizes and come back with your results.

### Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM MilestonesAndFlags AS MF,

  (SELECT max(id) AS id
   FROM MilestonesAndFlags
   WHERE milestone=1
   GROUP BY milestone,
            site_id) AS MaxMF
WHERE MaxMF.id = MF.id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0d628/10

### Pros and Cons:

**Pro:**
Avoidance of dependent subquery.

**Cons:**

- Join causes projection and selection. This causes all rows of temp table to be "multiplied" with rows of original table and then where condition filters.

### Update

I suspect also that the version of mysql plays a major role in the optimizations done. 
Below the explain results for 2 different mysql versions where one defined the subquery as dependent and the other as not.

MySQL 5.5.32

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE     TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY     KEY_LEN     REF     ROWS    EXTRA
1   PRIMARY     MilestonesAndFlags  ALL     (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  29  Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  MilestonesAndFlags  ref     milestone,milestone_2   milestone_2     9   const   15  Using where; Using index
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0d628/11

MySQL MySQL 5.6.6 m9

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE     TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY     KEY_LEN     REF     ROWS    EXTRA
1   PRIMARY     MilestonesAndFlags  ALL     (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  29  Using where; Using filesort
2   SUBQUERY    MilestonesAndFlags  ref     milestone,milestone_2   milestone_2     9   const   15  Using where; Using index
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0d62/2

Comment: @user3797030 Try updating your mysql to a higher version >5.6 and run again. I think your original query may be fastest then due to optimizations that detect that the subquery is not dependent (and hence will only run once).